# I can view PDF file on emulator only nut not on a real device in Flutter application

Tags: flutter, pdf, mobile, emulation, viewer

I used import 'package:advance_pdf_viewer/advance_pdf_viewer.dart'; to view PDF files from the an asset directory, it works well on the emulator but when I installed the APK file on my mobile, the indicator spin and the PDF file is not displayed, also no crash for the application

and notice that there a message in the console but at the same time the file is displayed on the emulator
A resource failed to call close.
I/ple.flutter_ap(12020): NativeAlloc concurrent copying GC freed 1875(113KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 53% free, 1355KB/2MB, paused 6.847ms total 92.795ms

I searched on the net and I tried the following solution but it didn't work

Add this line of code to it:

-keep class com.shockwave.** { *; }
Now in your app level build.gradle file, add this to your buildType:

proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
So that your buildType folder looks something like this:

buildTypes {
release {
minifyEnabled true
shrinkResources true
proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
}
}
enter code here

This is the code of getting the PDF file and it works well but only on the emulator

```
loadDocument() async {
    document = await PDFDocument.fromAsset('assets/sample4.pdf');

    setState(() => _isLoading = false);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is related to memory and anti-virus, so I deleted or unneeded code and asked the anti-virus to resolve any issue with the APK file and the application after the installation